# Z3 Conditional Statement

Tags: conditional-statements, z3, solver

How to write a conditional statement in Z3.

```
eg: 
if (a%2==0){
value=1
}
```

I am trying to achieve this in Z3 Solver by Microsoft Research but so far no luck

Comment: First note that Z3 expressions do not encode programs directly. There is no direct notion of side-effect in an expression. 

You can build an "if-then-else" expression from any of the APIs exposed by Z3.

Answer (score 2):

Look up SSA form: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form

Essentially, you'll have to change your program to look something like:

```
value_0 = 0
value_1 = (a%2 == 0) ? 1 : value_0
```

Once it is in this so called static single assignment form, you can now translate each line more or less directly; with the latest assignment to `value_N` being the final value of `value`.

Loops will be problematic: The usual strategy is to unroll them up to a certain count (bounded model checking), and hope that this suffices. If you detect that the last unrolling isn't sufficient, then you can generate an uninterpreted value at that point; which might cause your proofs to fail with spurious counter-examples; but that's the best you can do without a scheme that involves proper handling of induction and loop-invariants.

Note that this field of study is called "symbolic execution" and has a long history, with active research still being conducted. You might want to read through this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_execution