# How to generate a model for my code using boolector?

Tags: smt

I'm experimenting a bit with [boolector](https://boolector.github.io/) so I'm trying to create model for simple code. Suppose that I have the following pseudo code:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 4;
int c = 3;
```

For this simple set of instructions I can create the model and all works fine. The problem is when I have other instructions after that like

```
b = 10;
c = 20;
```

Obviously it fails to generate the model because `b` cannot be equal to `4` and `10` within the same module. One of the maintainer suggested me to use `boolector_push` and `boolector_pop` in order to create new `Context`s when needed.

The code for `boolector_push` is :

```
void
boolector_push (Btor *btor, uint32_t level)
{
  BTOR_ABORT_ARG_NULL (btor);
  BTOR_TRAPI ("%u", level);
  BTOR_ABORT (!btor_opt_get (btor, BTOR_OPT_INCREMENTAL),
              "incremental usage has not been enabled");

  if (level == 0) return;

  uint32_t i;
  for (i = 0; i < level; i++)
  {
    BTOR_PUSH_STACK (btor->assertions_trail,
                     BTOR_COUNT_STACK (btor->assertions));
  }
  btor->num_push_pop++;
}
```

Instead for `boolector_pop` is

```
void
boolector_pop (Btor *btor, uint32_t level)
{
  BTOR_ABORT_ARG_NULL (btor);
  BTOR_TRAPI ("%u", level);
  BTOR_ABORT (!btor_opt_get (btor, BTOR_OPT_INCREMENTAL),
              "incremental usage has not been enabled");
  BTOR_ABORT (level > BTOR_COUNT_STACK (btor->assertions_trail),
              "can not pop more levels (%u) than created via push (%u).",
              level,
              BTOR_COUNT_STACK (btor->assertions_trail));

  if (level == 0) return;

  uint32_t i, pos;
  BtorNode *cur;

  for (i = 0, pos = 0; i < level; i++)
    pos = BTOR_POP_STACK (btor->assertions_trail);

  while (BTOR_COUNT_STACK (btor->assertions) > pos)
  {
    cur = BTOR_POP_STACK (btor->assertions);
    btor_hashint_table_remove (btor->assertions_cache, btor_node_get_id (cur));
    btor_node_release (btor, cur);
  }
  btor->num_push_pop++;
}
```

In my opinion, those 2 functions maintains track of the assertions generated using `boolector_assert` so how is it possible to obtain the final and correct model using `boolector_push` and `boolector_pop` considering that the constraints are going to be the same?

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suspected, solver's `push` and `pop` methods aren't what you're looking for here. Instead, you have to turn the program you are modeling into what's known as SSA (Static Single Assignment) form. Here's the wikipedia article on it, which is quite informative: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form

The basic idea is that you "treat" your mutable variables as time-varying values, and give them unique names as you make multiple assignments to them. So, the following:

```
a = 5
b = a + 2
c = b + 3
c = c + 1
b = c + 6
```

becomes:

```
a0 = 5
b0 = a0 + 2
c0 = b0 + 3
c1 = c0 + 1
b1 = c1 + 6
```

etc. Note that conditionals are tricky to deal with, and generally require what's known as phi-nodes. (i.e., merging the values of branches.) Most compilers do this sort of conversion automatically for you, as it enables many optimizations down the road. You can either do it by hand, or use an algorithm to do it for you, depending on your particular problem.

Here's another question on stack-overflow, that's essentially asking for something similar: [Z3 Conditional Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44314486/z3-conditional-statement/44333232#44333232)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi @alias thanks for the answer. The thing I'd like to avoid is to have multiple boolector nodes that refer to the same byte in memory. Please imagine a boolector_array which represents an array in memory.. every time I assign a value to it I need to have a new node that keeps track of the value.. in my head it is a waste of resource so I was trying to find a way to avoid it

Comment: In addition I'd be happy to retract a constraint added with boolector_assert but I don't know if it is going to be fine for me. If I assign 2 values to the same node I'm only interested into the last value. I hope this helps..

Comment: You really can't avoid SSA in SMT-based modeling, it's just how things work, instead of imperative updates. But you shouldn't really worry about creating nodes: Boolector will internally garbage collect them I'm sure. (This claim needs to be checked, but it is almost always the case for other solvers.) If you do actually have efficiency issues, I'd say they'd be inherent to the problem. Of course, talking in the abstract doesn't really help: I recommend using this encoding, and ask again if you run into actual efficiency related issues.